# rails rspec capybara cannot get my internal api to connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, selenium, rspec

Constructing a basic rails app I'm re-factoring to do  heavy lifting on an external docker/compute as a service i.e. iron.io. the 'worker'

In refactoring created Grape API to allow status of processing from remote 'worker' to notify the server when processing is done. The user interface then uses ajax to poll the local server to update. API and basic tests all ok. It also works in development using Delayed::job running the worker.

I however cannot seem to get my capybara tests to work end to end as the delayed::job running process making the HTTP request back to the server always gets connection refused.

It works fine if i run a rails server in parallel as the tests: (`RAILS_ENV="test" rails s -p 3001`), then make sure the ENV variable is set to port 3001.

I had tried

- various combination of Capybara.configure (as below)
- in the test: visit url (where `url="http://#{Capybara.server_host}:#{Capybara.server_port}"` ) to see if that 'kicks off' the server perhaps
- various webdrivers (poltergeist, selenium etc)

Any thoughts, experience or guidance much appreciated

Ben

note: in the code

- populate the domain & port via ENV[''] variables that are populated (these environment variables will be set in the running environment iron.io)
- port & app_host set as below
- ENV variables populated in the test

  ```
  Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.run_server = true
    config.server_port = "9876"
    config.app_host = "http://127.0.0.1:9876"
  end
  ```

  rails  4.1.0
     rspec 3.4.0
     capybara 2.7.0
     poltergeist 1.5.1
     selenium 2.53.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to have your test too *too much*. I would recommend that you "mock out" the interactions with the other service to make the tests self sufficient. In the past I have added a `test.js` that:

- Mocks out ajax on the page
- Checks for specific requests to have been made (`page.evaluate_script`)
- Responds back to them in the way your external service will (`execute_script`)

Like this:

```
# test.js
$.ajax = function(settings) {
    window.__ajaxRequests || (window.__ajaxRequests = []);
    window.__ajaxRequests.push(settings);

    return {
        done: function(cb) { settings.__done = cb; }
    }
}

# spec/features/jobs_spec.rb
visit '/jobs'
click_button 'Start job'

requests = page.evaulate_script('window.__ajaxRequests')
expect(requests.size).to eq(1)
expect(requests[0].url).to eq('http://jobs.yourproduct.com/start')
...

expect(page).not_to have_content('Job completed')
page.execute_script('window.__ajaxRequests[0].__done({data:{status:"complete"}})')

expect(page).to have_content('Job completed')
```

Comment: Thanks Nort - i see your point, and could definitely have some tests that are 'just front-end' but it seems to me that full end to end integration test to ensure end to end customer experience works should be part of the test suite - surely you can't have unit/assembly tests only ?

Comment: @Ben it is effectively and end-to-end test of all of the components internal to the *app you're testing*. A test that integrates multiple system has to be written from an elevated perspective -- maybe an API test (runscope.com comes to mind).